# Install and run ASP.NET Core on IIS as an Application (not Site)

Tags: iis, asp.net-core

I have a ASP.NET Core web application. It works well, no problem with programming. I want it to be hosted on IIS so I set all needed things (.UseKestrel().UseIISIntegration()), setup unmanaged pool, grant access to IIS AppPool\myapplicationpool, copy published files to the Site's directory and I'm able to run it on IIS as **Site**. I type http://myapplication.net and I got the response from IIS.

---

But I would like to run it as the **Application** of the Site. And add more applications like this to the Site later. Like http://myapplication.net/app1, http://myapplication.net/app2 etc.
But this doesn't work for me. I create the Site on IIS and set the unmanaged pool. Then I add the application to the Site, create folders, grant access, copy published application to the Application folder but when I type http://myapplication.net/app1, I got the 502 HTTP error saying that Application cannot be started.
Do you know what can be wrong? I'm missing something for sure. Some settings in web.config? (I have just one web.config created by Publish process at the level of the application and none at Site level). Or maybe .UseWebRoot("some_directory") must be set in a particular way? IIS binding? Or it is not possible at all? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Did you install the .NET Core Hosting Bundle? Go to your IIS and check you have on `Modules` the `AspNetCoreModule` listed.

Comment: Yes, of course. As I said: hosting works well if the application is running as a Site of IIS. What I want is to have a IIS Site and under it add many IIS Applications.

Comment: Have you checked the event logs? What's the error message? I just created a brand new api, created a Website with a simple html file on the root, and added my api as an Application. All working.

Comment: What HTML page? When I compile and publish .NET Core web application, there is no HTML page. Just bunch of dll, json and web config.

Comment: I created a new Website on IIS. At the root, I just put it a .html file. If I browse to localhost:27001 I see my Hello world html. Then, under this website I created a Application that points to my ASPNET Core api. Then, I navigate to localhost:27001/api/home and I hit my api's home controller.

Comment: Ensure your application has web.config has the following code:
 <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="aspNetCore"/>
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified"/>
    </handlers>
    <aspNetCore processPath="%LAUNCHER_PATH%" arguments="%LAUNCHER_ARGS%" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" />
  </system.webServer>

Also, create a logs folder inside published folder and check if error is logged in a file under the logs folder.

Comment: Have you chosen the "No Managed Code" for your Application Pool? @OndrejVencovsky

Comment: Any more details on that 502 error page? Do you still have a Core app at the root site? Web.configs are inherited, you need to add that handler remove flag mohsin showed above to avoid a conflict.